# lightning-record-edit-form not displaying help text in community

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, helptext

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account">
       <lightning-input-field field-name='Name'></lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

above peice of code displays the help text of the field if the component is used inside salesforce org. But if it's used in the community help text is not displayed. Any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to ditch `lightning-record-edit-form` and use `getObjectInfo` from [uiObjectInfoApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) and `getRecord` from [uiRecordApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record)

I have created a custom-record-edit-form earlier that fetches data and metadata, you can refer it.

Markup:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={complexAccount}>
        <template for:each={complexAccount} for:item=field>
            <lightning-input key={field.apiName} label={field.label} value={field.value}
                             field-level-help={field.inlineHelpText}></lightning-input>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement , wire , api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Phone';

export default class Accountpage extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '0012600000xI6vh', fields: [NAME_FIELD,PHONE_FIELD] })
        account;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
        accountObjectInfo;

    get complexAccount(){
        let ac = [];
        if(this.account.data && this.accountObjectInfo.data){
        Object.keys(this.account.data.fields).forEach(ele => {
                var indElement;
                indElement = {...this.account.data.fields[ele]};
                indElement.inlineHelpText = this.accountObjectInfo.data.fields[ele].inlineHelpText;
                indElement.apiName = this.accountObjectInfo.data.fields[ele].apiName;
                indElement.label = this.accountObjectInfo.data.fields[ele].label;
                ac.push(indElement);
        });
        return ac;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How can i get the picklist values from the schema for the user to select ? I'm trying on new record creation not editing. Thanks

Comment: You can look into [getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values)